# Group two dfs with a column and concat the all row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

Merge two dfs based on col1 values with col2 values concatenated.

My df1:

```
col1  col2      

Arm   'a'
Arm   'b'
Abc   'c' 
Abc   'd'  
Xzc   'e'
```

My df2:

```
col1     col2 

Abc    '1'
Arm    '2'
Abc    '3'
ers    '4'
```

Thing is to merge the dfs like

```
merged_c1   merged_c2 
Arm         'a 2'
Arm         'b 2'
Abc         'c 1'
Abc         'c 3'
Abc         'd 1'
Abc         'd 3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with join columns with [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='col1')

#if not necessary remove trailing '
#df['col2'] = df.pop('col2_x') + ' ' + df.pop('col2_y')

df['col2'] = df.pop('col2_x').str.strip("'") + ' ' + df.pop('col2_y').str.strip("'")
print (df)
  col1 col2
0  Arm  a 2
1  Arm  b 2
2  Abc  c 1
3  Abc  c 3
4  Abc  d 1
5  Abc  d 3
```